# How do I sketch the following metrics:

Tags: metric-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ sketch $B((1,2),3)$, the open ball of radius $3$ at the point $(1,2)$, with the following metrics:

a.) the post-office metric given by
$$d(x,y) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
     \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}+\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}, & \quad \text{if $x\neq y$}\\
     0, & \quad \text{if $x=y$}
   \end{array} \right.$$
for $x=(x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

b.) the metric $$d(x,y)=\frac{5\| x-y\|_2}{1+\| x-y\|_2}.$$

Comment: Should it be $\|x-y\|^2$?

Comment: @Sigur I think there is no problem with assuming it is the Euclidean distance. This does define an equivalent distance.

Comment: According to the question it's $\parallel x-y\parallel_2$.

Answer (score 2):

(a) circle of radius $\sqrt{0.58}$ centered at $(0,0)$

(b) circle of radius $\frac12$ centered at $(1,2)$
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372924/14108) for the calculation in (b).

[image]