# Is it possible to use the matrix element-wise max norm when checking if a vector-valued map is a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. Using the MVT for vector-valued function
$$
f(x)-f(y)= \nabla f(c) \cdot (x-y),
$$
for some $c$ on a curve connecting $x$ and $y$.

If 
$$
\| \nabla f(c) \|_{max} = \max_{i,j} \left| (\nabla f(c))_{i,j} \right| \le \lambda,
$$
for any $c$, can I infer that $f$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $\lambda$?
That is, to conclude
$$
\|f(x) - f(y) \| \le \lambda \|x-y\|? 
$$
I asked because some reference infer that $f$ is Lipschitz using a matrix norm on the Jacobian,
while [wikipedia](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372924/14108) mentioned that the Jacobian should only be bounded.

For example, for
$$
f(x,y)=\left( \frac{2}{1/x+1/y},\sqrt{xy}\right), \text{ with } x,y \in [1,2],
$$
then, element-wise,
$$
\nabla f \le \begin{pmatrix} \frac{8}{9} & \frac{8}{9} \\ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \end{pmatrix},
$$
so
\begin{align}
\|\nabla f \|_{max} &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} < 1, \\
\|\nabla f \|_1 & =\frac{8}{9}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} > 1 \\
\|\nabla f \|_\infty & =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} > 1
\end{align}
So that only by using $\|\cdot\|_{max}$, I can conclude that $f$ is a contractive map.
That is I would like to conclude
$$
\|f(x)-f(y)\|_1 \le \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \|x-y\|_1. 
$$

Comment: Consider $f(x)=(x_1+x_2,x_1+x_2)$. Then $\max\nabla f=1$, but $f(1,1)=(2,2)$, so the best upper bound is $|f(x)-f(y)|\le 2|x-y|$. I think this is the worst case, though, so if you double your bound, it should work. (It won't be proven contractive, though, in your example.) (In your parlance, $\| \nabla f(c) \|_{max} = \max_{i,j} \left| (\nabla f(c))_{i,j} \right| \le \lambda\implies\|f(x) - f(y) \| \le 2\lambda \|x-y\|$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> some reference infer that f is Lipschitz using a matrix norm on the Jacobian, while wikipedia mentioned that the Jacobian should only be bounded.

To show that a differentiable map $f:\mathbb R^2\mathbb R^2$ is Lipschitz, it is sufficient to prove a uniform bound for *some* norm of its Jacobian matrix. It does not matter which norm you choose: $\max_{ij} |a_{ij}|$, $\sum_{ij} |a_{ij}|$,  $\left(\sum_{ij} |a_{ij}|^2\right)^{1/2}$, the operator norm $\max_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|$, or something else. Any two norms on a finite dimensional vector space are comparable.

But if want to determine the Lipschitz constant of $f$, the right norm to use is the operator norm $\max_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|$. Indeed, the operator norm of the Jacobian matrix at point $a$ is equal to $\limsup_{x\to a}\dfrac{\|f(x)-f(a)\|}{\|x-a\|}$. From here (and the mean value theorem) one obtains that the supremum of the operator norm is equal to the  Lipschitz constant of $f$.